# httpwebrequest with events vb2008

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, httpwebrequest

Is it possibl to get events of httpwebrequest? for example whn i make a post request, then in the events procedure i should be getting something like this in the following order say

- connecting to website
- connected to website
- posting request
- request posted
- waiting for response
- receiving response
- response received
- disconnecting
- disconnected

Or how to i implement something like this with the webrequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class instead. This class offers several events, although not all of the ones you're looking for.